# Show how a projectile (turtle) travels over time

Tags: python, turtle-graphics

I am new to Python, and currently having a rough time with turtle graphics. This is what I am trying to solve

> On Turtellini (the planet where Python turtles live) the
>   transportation system propels turtles with a giant slingshot. A
>   particular turtle's original location (x0, y0) is (-180, -100). He is
>   then shot upward at an initial vertical velocity (vy) of 88 units per
>   second and a horizontal velocity (vx) of 20 units per second to the
>   right. He travels for 16 seconds. The acceleration due to gravity (g)
>   is 11 units per second squared. The the location of the turtle at a
>   given second (t) is calculated as follows: x = x0 + vx * t and y = y0
>   + vy * t - g/2 * t2 . This program is to show how a turtle travels over this period of time.

The output should be like this:

[image: Output Image]

Here is what I should do;

- set up the constants (vertical velocity, horizontal velocity,
  gravity) and variables (x and y coordinates) set up the turtle by
  giving him a proper shape, putting his tail up, moving him to the
  initial position, putting his tail down make a loop that repeats for
  seconds 1 through 16 inclusive. in each iteration of the loop display
  the the values of the x and y variables (in the shell window), move
  the turtle to those coordinates, have the turtle stamp his shape,
  calculate the new values for the x and y variables after the loop
  terminates, move the turtle to the last calculated coordinates,
  change his color, and stamp his shape, then wait for a mouse click

My code so far:

```
import turtle

def main():
    wn = turtle.Screen()
    turtellini = turtle.Turtle()
    t = int(input("Blab blab blab: "))
    x0 = -180
    y0 = -100
    vx = 20
    vy = 88
    g = 11
    x = (float(x0 + vx * t))
    y = (float(y0 + vy * t - g / 2 * t**2))
    turtellini.color("black")
    turtellini.shape("turtle")
    turtellini.up()
    turtellini.goto(-180,-100)
    turtellini.down()
    for i in range(1,16,1):
        turtellini.stamp()
        turtellini.forward(i)
        turtellini.right(i)
    print(x)
    print(y)
if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

I know I am doing bad; but can anyone help me to solve this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You seem to have most of the parts and pieces.  The biggest issue I see is you didn't put your x,y calculation in the loop.  The loop iteration variable `i` is really `t` in your motion equations.  Each time you calculate a new x,y you simply move the turtle to that position:

```
import turtle
from math import pi, atan

x0, y0 = -180, -100  # initial location

vx, vy = 20.0, 88.0  # initial velocity in units per second

travel_time = 16  # seconds

g = 11.0  # acceleration due to gravity in units per second squared

turtellini = turtle.Turtle(shape='turtle', visible=False)

turtellini.penup()
turtellini.radians()  # to make turtle compatible with math.atan()
turtellini.setheading(pi / 2)  # straight up
turtellini.goto(x0, y0)
turtellini.pendown()
turtellini.showturtle()
turtellini.stamp()

for t in range(1, travel_time + 1):

    x = x0 + vx * t
    y = y0 + vy * t - g / 2 * t**2

    turtellini.goto(x, y)

    print(x, y)

    angle = atan((vy * t - g * t**2) / (vx * t))  # a guess!
    turtellini.setheading(angle)

    turtellini.stamp()

turtle.exitonclick()
```

Unlike the gold standard image, I assumed the turtle was aerodynamic like a bullet and travelled head first through the flight.  I don't know, and couldn't quickly find, the formula for the flight angle of a projectile so I guessed from the existing formulas:

[image]